# Generating YouTube Data API v3 keys via CLI

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I'm generating YouTube Data API v3 keys via Google Console and wondering if there is a way in generating it via CLI?

Comment: No. There's none.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [google apis console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) is used to register your application with google. You can create api key as well as oauth credentials there.

This must be done manually there is no api for doing this nor is their a CLI which will allow you to access the [google apis console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard).

Comment: I see. Thanks for this. I guess I have no other choice but to do it manually. :)